# How to convert this MySQL query into PostgreSQL which uses nested subqueries?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

MySQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
  (SELECT count(*) AS TC FROM tc where pID='22') AS tCount,
  (SELECT count(*) AS SC FROM sc where pID='22') AS sCount,
  (SELECT count(*) AS RS FROM results where pID='22'and isDeleted=false and status<>'Running')as rCount
)
```

However this does not work on PostgreSQL. I get this error:

> syntax error at position 92 near tCount

ie. the error is at ','.

How can we translate this query to PostgreSQL? I tried with a `WITH` query in PostgreSQL but I am not getting what script is needed to fulfill the requirement of the statement.

I tried this PostgreSQL translated query:

```
WITH tCount AS
(
  SELECT count(*) AS TC FROM tc where pID='22'
), sCount AS
(
  SELECT count(*) AS SC FROM sc where pID='22'
), rCount AS
(
  SELECT count(*) AS RS FROM results where pID='22'and isDeleted=false and status<>'Running'
)
```

Is my approach correct? If yes then how can I complete this script. And if not, then what is the translation of above MySQL query into PostgreSQL query?

Comment: Every subquery can be written as a `JOIN`. Rewrite your subqueries into `JOIN`s. Also, try to format your code in the future, it shows politeness towards people trying to help you since it makes it easier on them to read your problem.

Comment: isn't there any way to write the query in postgresql without join??..

Comment: Doesn't the first query run as it is?

Comment: @N.B whats the logic behind every subquery being equivalent with a join query ( is there a proof )

Comment: @halfer PostgreSQL doesn't seem to allow `(SELECT ...) as a, (SELECT ...) as b)` type of structure.

Comment: @halfer Mysql query runs successfully but when i translate this to postgresql syntax it shows error....

Comment: It is quite normal here, when mentioning "an error", to divulge what that error actually says. Any chance? `:-)`

Comment: A little comment on case sensitivity. If you have column names with capital letters you need to reference them in double quotes. I.e. if your column is "isDeleted", you need to put that in double quotes, otherwise Postgresql will look for the lower case column name, which doesn't exist, and cough.

Comment: its syntax error at position 92 near tCount, ie. error is at ','.

Comment: @amdixon - every subquery can be expressed as a JOIN. That's a fact, I can't really link you with a theoretical proof because I don't have one and googling right now would be cheating :) but essentially, subqueries and joins are the same - with JOINs actually being easier for databases to parse (and ultimately execute).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (untested):

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tc WHERE pID='22') AS tCount,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sc WHERE pID='22') AS sCount,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM results
   WHERE pID='22' AND isDeleted=false
   AND status<>'Running') AS rCount
```

I've just changed your subquery virtual tables into subquery virtual columns, fixed the case of some statements for tidiness, and removed some column aliasing that wasn't needed.

---

Edit: my original answer featured a [`DUAL`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_table) table, which is a dummy table on some database systems used to complete a query that does not select directly from real tables. Since it didn't work in your case, I've removed it - and as per the Wikipedia article, a `FROM` clause is not required in PostgreSQL anyway.

Comment: Have you tried it, @Akash? Try it with and without the `DUAL` at the end - the Wikipedia article says that a `FROM` clause is not necessary on PostgreSQL.

Comment: Seems to work without the "DUAL" and cough with it. At least on my 9.3 set up.

Comment: Thanks @mlinth. I've used DUAL on PostgreSQL, but the article suggests it is created as a view rather than being natively available.

Comment: Thanks @halfer it works without DUAL..... with dual shows error that relation dual not exists..

Comment: OK, great @Akash. And you've learnt about DUAL tables now also, which is no bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the outer brackets. This works:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 

  (SELECT count(*) AS TC FROM tc where pID='22') AS tCount,
  (SELECT count(*) AS SC FROM sc where pID='22') AS sCount,
  (SELECT count(*) AS RS FROM results where pID='22'
                                            and isDeleted=false 
                                            and status<>'Running')as rCount
```

note that the column names are "tc","sc" and "rs". If you want "tCount" etc. you have to change the aliases after the `count(*)` statements.